# Update developer story privacy settings to be more clear

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

Currently the developer story defaults to private and when you click update privacy it takes you to another page where you can manage settings.

There is a checkbox with a label: "Show the developer story tab"
This does not sound like a privacy setting but a UX preference.

However, when you click it it somehow makes my developer story public.

Please update the wording of this checkbox or separate them into separate preferences. 1 for my link being visible to anyone who I give it to, and another to update my UI to show a special tab.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the feedback!

The "Show the Developer story tab" checkbox controls the visibility of the Developer Story to other users while the "Always visible" checkbox allows your story to be available via the public link if it is hidden on your profile.

We're about to start work on new privacy controls for Developer Story to make them simpler and easier to use. Your feedback has been noted and we'll able to share some updates soon.

Comment: I don't get anything of what you write in the first paragraph.

Can someone please carefully explain the definition of and difference between the two check boxes "show tab" versus "always visible"?

Comment: @MartinAndersson "Show tab" relates to your Stack Overflow profile and controls if the Developer Story tab is visible to other users. "Always visible" relates to the public link for your Developer Story (https://stackoverflow.com/story/<username>) and allows you to maintain your public profile even if "Show tab" is unchecked and your Developer Story is hidden from your profile.

Comment: @Kit thanks for clarifying. Where can I go to make a few suggestions regarding Dev Stories?